# How to create a list of consecutive git diffs between two branches in svn format?

Tags: git, svn, diff, git-svn

I have a git repository (actually a git-svn repository), I created a new branch and made several commits. on the local branch. Now I would like to get diff between all commits made on the branch. Lets say I have 5 commits between the original state and the current state:

```
2792959ffd30fc54f56f82fa786b3bd9396e607a
c006fcd294957761dcced3c88760c357af1c3613
05d16d49def746b24f74e1306e16999f13e90027
2d87f52dbe82df507a29a725b0f954c6d7abfc82
66af1018d4f5621a7d021f98dc392e80ca826d35
```

Then I want to have a listing of all four (4) indicidual diffs between each commit, in SVN version (i.e. as if you had createed the diffs with svn diff).

To be precise: I want to see

1. The commit message for each commit
2. The differences made in the various files that has changed
3. Optionally: git commit hash

Comment: what is wrong with `git log $somehash..$otherhash`? you do not have to use actual hashes, you can also use `HEAD` and `HEAD^`...

Comment: Because with log I only see the log messages. I want to see the diffs for each commit...

Comment: and with `--full-diff`

Comment: do you want to see 4 separate diffs in one command or do you want to see 1 diff containing the changes from all 4 commits?

Answer (score 0):

To get a full list of what has changed between two branches or two commits you can use `git whatchanged`

i.e.

```
git whatchanged -p 66af1018d4f5621a7d021f98dc392e80ca826d35 2792959ffd30fc54f56f82fa786b3bd9396e607a
```

The `-p` flag tells git to use the textual diff rather than a hexadecimal diff. See https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-whatchanged.html

Answer (score 0):

i think you can simply do

```
git log --full-diff $somehash..$otherhash
```

and you can use `HEAD` and `HEAD^` instead of full hashes to refer to commits.

Comment: Shows only the log entries, NOT the diffs.

Answer (score 0):

possibly even better:

```
git show $somehash
```